# C# HttpClient: Why MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient

What is the purpose of the MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue parameter when attempting to set the "Content-Type" header property on a request? [The MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypewithqualityheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx) simply states:

> Represents a content-type header value with an additional quality.

What specifically is meant by 'an additional quality'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose is to comply with the HTTP standard, which under section 3.9 defines quality values. You can read further about it in RFC 2616. Here is a link :  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

Comment: Interesting, so what "q" value does MediaTypeWithQualityHeader set for say a header value of "Content-Type: application/json" and why isn't the string sufficient?  The MSDN doc just says "an additional quality" as shown in my original question?

Comment: The q-value is used to specify priorities for a list (for example, a list of media-types in the Accept header). The higher the number assigned to a list-item, the more it is preferred by the application. 0 would denote that it is absolutely unwanted. In our scenario with the Accept header, if the server does not support the type with the highest q-value, then it will fall to the next highest q-value.

Comment: In the case that you only have one item, it likely defaults the q-value to 1. Otherwise, the alternative two parameter constructor allows for you to set the q-value for that item, so when you have multiple items you can specify the q-value. The HttpClient doesn't impose this as an additional complexity, this is simply a requirement of the HTTP protocol. Maybe you doubt the particular implementation, but if you ask me it is fairly straight forward if you understand the protocol.